# Vertex degree in De Bruijn graphs

Tags: algorithms, graphs

How can I find the degree of a vertex in a De Bruijn graph? Also, given a vertex, is there an easy way to find which other vertices it is connected to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both questions can be answered by looking at the rules for constructing a De Bruijn graph:

1. We have a set of symbols $S$, and a number $n$.
2. There is a vertex for each element of $S^{n}$, labelled as such - i.e. one for each sequence of symbols from $S$ of length $n$, the same symbol can appear multiple times in the sequence.
3. If the label of vertex $v$ can be obtained from the label of vertex $u$ by removing the first symbol and appending a new symbol to the end, there is a directed edge from $u$ to $v$ (i.e. $(u,v)$ is an arc).

It should be clear that both the out-degree and the in-degree are $|S|$ - one incoming and one outgoing edge for each symbol in $S$. Remeber that every sequence of symbols appears somewhere, so no matter how we apply rule 3, the resulting sequence is somewhere in the graph. Similarly the reverse of rule 3 works for every possible symbol.

Rule three also tells us the neighbours, just perform rule 3 for with every symbol to get the out-neighbourhood, and reverse rule 3 with every symbol to get the in-neighbourhood.

Some examples, plus these and additional properties can also be found on the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_graph).